# Многомерный массив JSON и PHP

Tags: php, json

У меня есть массивы:

```
    'response' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'barcode' => '',
      'category_name' => 'Кофе',
      'unit' => 'kg',
      'cost' => '791',
      'fiscal' => '0',
      'hidden' => '0',
      'menu_category_id' => '1',
      'workshop' => '1',
      'nodiscount' => '0',
      'photo' => '/upload/pos_cdb_7631/menu/product_1464608672_3.jpg',
      'photo_origin' => '/upload/pos_cdb_7631/menu/product_1464608672_3_original.jpg',
      'price' => 
      array (
        1 => '3000',
        2 => '3000',
      ),
      'product_code' => '',
      'product_id' => '3',
      'product_name' => 'Капучино 250 мл',
      'profit' => 
      array (
        1 => '2209',
        2 => '2209',
      ),
      'sort_order' => '999',
      'tax_id' => '0',
      'product_tax_id' => '0',
      'type' => '2',
      'weight_flag' => '0',
      'color' => 'white',
      'spots' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'spot_id' => '1',
          'price' => '3000',
          'profit' => '2209',
          'visible' => '0',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'spot_id' => '2',
          'price' => '3000',
          'profit' => '2209',
          'visible' => '0',
        ),
      ),
      'ingredient_id' => '0',
      'out' => 248,
      'product_production_description' => '',
      'ingredients' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'structure_id' => '52',
          'ingredient_id' => '10',
          'pr_in_clear' => '0',
          'pr_in_cook' => '0',
          'pr_in_fry' => '0',
          'pr_in_stew' => '0',
          'pr_in_bake' => '0',
          'structure_unit' => 'l',
          'structure_type' => '1',
          'structure_brutto' => 30,
          'structure_netto' => 30,
          'structure_lock' => '1',
          'structure_selfprice' => '2',
          'ingredient_name' => 'Вода',
          'ingredient_unit' => 'l',
          'ingredient_weight' => 0,
          'ingredients_losses_clear' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_cook' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_fry' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_stew' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_bake' => '0',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'structure_id' => '53',
          'ingredient_id' => '9',
          'pr_in_clear' => '0',
          'pr_in_cook' => '0',
          'pr_in_fry' => '0',
          'pr_in_stew' => '0',
          'pr_in_bake' => '0',
          'structure_unit' => 'kg',
          'structure_type' => '1',
          'structure_brutto' => 8,
          'structure_netto' => 8,
          'structure_lock' => '1',
          'structure_selfprice' => '232',
          'ingredient_name' => 'Кофе',
          'ingredient_unit' => 'kg',
          'ingredient_weight' => 0,
          'ingredients_losses_clear' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_cook' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_fry' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_stew' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_bake' => '0',
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'structure_id' => '54',
          'ingredient_id' => '8',
          'pr_in_clear' => '0',
          'pr_in_cook' => '0',
          'pr_in_fry' => '0',
          'pr_in_stew' => '0',
          'pr_in_bake' => '0',
          'structure_unit' => 'l',
          'structure_type' => '1',
          'structure_brutto' => 150,
          'structure_netto' => 210,
          'structure_lock' => '0',
          'structure_selfprice' => '330',
          'ingredient_name' => 'Молоко',
          'ingredient_unit' => 'l',
          'ingredient_weight' => 0,
          'ingredients_losses_clear' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_cook' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_fry' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_stew' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_bake' => '0',
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
          'structure_id' => '55',
          'ingredient_id' => '7',
          'pr_in_clear' => '0',
          'pr_in_cook' => '0',
          'pr_in_fry' => '0',
          'pr_in_stew' => '0',
          'pr_in_bake' => '0',
          'structure_unit' => 'p',
          'structure_type' => '1',
          'structure_brutto' => 1,
          'structure_netto' => 0,
          'structure_lock' => '1',
          'structure_selfprice' => '190',
          'ingredient_name' => 'Бумажные стаканы 250 мл',
          'ingredient_unit' => 'p',
          'ingredient_weight' => 0,
          'ingredients_losses_clear' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_cook' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_fry' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_stew' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_bake' => '0',
        ),
        4 => 
        array (
          'structure_id' => '56',
          'ingredient_id' => '6',
          'pr_in_clear' => '0',
          'pr_in_cook' => '0',
          'pr_in_fry' => '0',
          'pr_in_stew' => '0',
          'pr_in_bake' => '0',
          'structure_unit' => 'p',
          'structure_type' => '1',
          'structure_brutto' => 1,
          'structure_netto' => 0,
          'structure_lock' => '1',
          'structure_selfprice' => '15',
          'ingredient_name' => 'Крышка 250 мл',
          'ingredient_unit' => 'p',
          'ingredient_weight' => 0,
          'ingredients_losses_clear' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_cook' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_fry' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_stew' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_bake' => '0',
        ),
        5 => 
        array (
          'structure_id' => '57',
          'ingredient_id' => '5',
          'pr_in_clear' => '0',
          'pr_in_cook' => '0',
          'pr_in_fry' => '0',
          'pr_in_stew' => '0',
          'pr_in_bake' => '0',
          'structure_unit' => 'p',
          'structure_type' => '1',
          'structure_brutto' => 1,
          'structure_netto' => 0,
          'structure_lock' => '1',
          'structure_selfprice' => '22',
          'ingredient_name' => 'Размешиватель',
          'ingredient_unit' => 'p',
          'ingredient_weight' => 0,
          'ingredients_losses_clear' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_cook' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_fry' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_stew' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_bake' => '0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'barcode' => '',
      'category_name' => 'Кофе',
      'unit' => 'kg',
      'cost' => '805',
      'fiscal' => '0',
      'hidden' => '0',
      'menu_category_id' => '1',
      'workshop' => '2',
      'nodiscount' => '0',
      'photo' => '/upload/pos_cdb_7631/menu/product_1464251849_5.jpg',
      'photo_origin' => '/upload/pos_cdb_7631/menu/product_1464251849_5_original.jpg',
      'price' => 
      array (
        1 => '1600',
        2 => '1600',
      ),
      'product_code' => '',
      'product_id' => '5',
      'product_name' => 'Круассан с шоколадом',
      'profit' => 
      array (
        1 => '795',
        2 => '795',
      ),
      'sort_order' => '999',
      'tax_id' => '0',
      'product_tax_id' => '0',
      'type' => '2',
      'weight_flag' => '0',
      'color' => 'white',
      'spots' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'spot_id' => '1',
          'price' => '1600',
          'profit' => '795',
          'visible' => '0',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'spot_id' => '2',
          'price' => '1600',
          'profit' => '795',
          'visible' => '0',
        ),
      ),
      'ingredient_id' => '0',
      'out' => 190,
      'product_production_description' => '',
      'ingredients' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'structure_id' => '62',
          'ingredient_id' => '17',
          'pr_in_clear' => '0',
          'pr_in_cook' => '0',
          'pr_in_fry' => '0',
          'pr_in_stew' => '0',
          'pr_in_bake' => '0',
          'structure_unit' => 'kg',
          'structure_type' => '1',
          'structure_brutto' => 30,
          'structure_netto' => 30,
          'structure_lock' => '1',
          'structure_selfprice' => '360',
          'ingredient_name' => 'Шоколад черный',
          'ingredient_unit' => 'kg',
          'ingredient_weight' => 0,
          'ingredients_losses_clear' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_cook' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_fry' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_stew' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_bake' => '0',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'structure_id' => '63',
          'ingredient_id' => '4',
          'pr_in_clear' => '0',
          'pr_in_cook' => '0',
          'pr_in_fry' => '0',
          'pr_in_stew' => '0',
          'pr_in_bake' => '0',
          'structure_unit' => 'kg',
          'structure_type' => '2',
          'structure_brutto' => 130,
          'structure_netto' => 160,
          'structure_lock' => '0',
          'structure_selfprice' => '445',
          'ingredient_name' => 'Тесто для круассанов',
          'ingredient_unit' => 'kg',
          'ingredient_weight' => 0,
          'ingredients_losses_clear' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_cook' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_fry' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_stew' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_bake' => '0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'barcode' => '',
      'category_name' => 'Кофе',
      'unit' => 'kg',
      'cost' => '15',
      'fiscal' => '0',
      'hidden' => '0',
      'menu_category_id' => '1',
      'workshop' => '0',
      'nodiscount' => '0',
      'photo' => '',
      'photo_origin' => NULL,
      'price' => 
      array (
        1 => '16681',
        2 => '16681',
      ),
      'product_code' => '',
      'product_id' => '10',
      'product_name' => 'Что то',
      'profit' => 
      array (
        1 => '16666',
        2 => '16666',
      ),
      'sort_order' => '999',
      'tax_id' => '0',
      'product_tax_id' => '0',
      'type' => '2',
      'weight_flag' => '0',
      'color' => 'white',
      'spots' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'spot_id' => '1',
          'price' => '16681',
          'profit' => '16666',
          'visible' => '1',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'spot_id' => '2',
          'price' => '16681',
          'profit' => '16666',
          'visible' => '1',
        ),
      ),
      'ingredient_id' => '0',
      'out' => 0,
      'product_production_description' => '',
      'ingredients' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'structure_id' => '66',
          'ingredient_id' => '6',
          'pr_in_clear' => '0',
          'pr_in_cook' => '0',
          'pr_in_fry' => '0',
          'pr_in_stew' => '0',
          'pr_in_bake' => '0',
          'structure_unit' => 'p',
          'structure_type' => '1',
          'structure_brutto' => 1,
          'structure_netto' => 0,
          'structure_lock' => '1',
          'structure_selfprice' => '15',
          'ingredient_name' => 'Крышка 250 мл',
          'ingredient_unit' => 'p',
          'ingredient_weight' => 0,
          'ingredients_losses_clear' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_cook' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_fry' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_stew' => '0',
          'ingredients_losses_bake' => '0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Как  я могу обработать автоматически (так как их может быть много) массив и вывести все ingredient_name через запятую в карточку товара, и в конце с точкой?

Должен получить

```
<div>
Вода, кофе, молоко, Стакан
</div>
<div>
Вода, кофе, молоко, Стакан
</div>
<div>
Что-то, что-то еще, молоко, Стакан
</div>
```

Comment: Покажите данные, которые должны быть на выходе

Comment: Совет вам на будущее: вместо `print_r()` распечатывайте и публикуйте дампы массивов с помощью [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-export.php). Разница в том, что для работы  с вашим опубликованным вариантом массива, его ещё понадобится "допиливать", а это мало кому интересно, и поэтому помощи вы можете ждать дольше.

Comment: array_column и implode очень вам помогут, ну и работа с циклами.

Comment: Сколько можно задавать одни и те же вопросы про `ingredient_name`?

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов - обойти массив с помощью [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
$array = array (
  'response' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'category_name' => 'Кофе',
      'ingredients' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'ingredient_name' => 'Вода',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'ingredient_name' => 'Кофе',
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'ingredient_name' => 'Молоко',
          ),
          3 => 
          array (
            'ingredient_name' => 'Бумажные стаканы 250 мл',
          ),
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'ingredient_name' => 'Вода',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'ingredient_name' => 'Кофе',
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'ingredient_name' => 'Молоко',
          ),
          3 => 
          array (
            'ingredient_name' => 'Бумажные стаканы 250 мл',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


$result = [];

array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key)use(&$result){
    $key != 'ingredient_name' ?: $result[] = $item;
});

$result = join(', ', array_unique($result)) . '.';

echo $result;
```

Результат:

```
Вода, Кофе, Молоко, Бумажные стаканы 250 мл.
```

Comment: Выводит все верно, но не разделяет по  карточкам товара, а для всех выводит весь текст

Comment: @ЗадатьВопрос из текущего контекста вашего вопроса нельзя понять, о каких карточках идёт речь, т.к. вы предоставили только исходный массив. Попробуйте самостоятельно обрабатывать _(подставлять его значения в т.н. "карточки")_ значения полученного массива $result.

Comment: Каждый массив это отдельный товар и ингредиенты надо выводить так

Товар 1
<div>
Вода, кофе, молоко, Стакан
</div>
Товар 2
<div>
Вода, кофе, молоко, Стакан
</div>
Товар 3
<div>
Что-то, что-то еще, молоко, Стакан
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Обновил обработчик в связи со сменой структуры данных.

```
// Собираем коллекцию ингридиентов
$data = array_reduce($data['response'], function($ret1, $lvl1){
  $subItems1 = array_reduce($lvl1['ingredients'], function($ret2, $lvl2){
      $ret2[] = $lvl2['ingredient_name'];
      return $ret2;
  }, []);
  $ret1[] = $subItems1;
  return $ret1;
}, []);


// Соединяем ингридиенты в разделы
$sections = array_map(function($list){
  return implode(', ', $list);
}, $data);

// Ставим последнему точку
$sections[] = array_pop($sections) . '.';

// Выводим с экранированием
array_walk($sections, function($str){
  echo '<div>' . htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_HTML5) . '</div>';
});
```

Результат:

```
<div>Вода, Кофе, Молоко, Бумажные стаканы 250 мл, Крышка 250 мл, Размешиватель</div>
<div>Шоколад черный, Тесто для круассанов</div>
<div>Крышка 250 мл.</div>
```

Comment: А если у меня будет такой массив (изменил в вопросе)

Comment: вы хотите универсальное решение, основанное не на разметке документа, а на `ingredients > ingredient_name`?

Comment: Да, я хочу чтоб обработало массив каждого товара и для каждого товара вывести его ингредиенты

Comment: Тот что сейчас вариант верный, но он может обработать только один главный массив

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: да, все верно Только один вопрос, я могу вывести не через echo, а $output .= <div class="item">
<h1>Товар 1</h1> 
Сюда ингредиенты
</div> 
И так для всех

Comment: Да, никто не запрещает

Comment: А не подскажешь как это лучше сделать

Comment: И еще, как я могу получить еще параметры product_name и price